# iOS 14 WKWebView body scroll issue

Tags: javascript, css, safari, wkwebview, ios14

Is there any way to disable body scroll for react web application when it opened in "in app browser"? For example I have link to react web app posted to twitter. When I open it from twitter app, it opens in app browser and there is issue with body scroll. After I open it via safari there is no any issues. The issue has place only on **iOS 14**[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/471wm.jpg) Please look at the screenshot. Only block below map should be scrollable. I blocked scroll of the body via `body {  overflow: hidden; height: 100%; }`
link to the twitter post (to reproduce issue should be open from twitter app or another app) https://twitter.com/a1test3/status/1306352481358807041?s=21